Curvature of Curve Represented as the Graph of Function on Surface
I read a paper, and there is a statement in it that I don't fully understand.
Assume the surface has a local coordinate  $(x,y)$, in this local coordinate, there is a curve $y=f(x)$. The author states that
$$
k = \frac{d^2 y / dx^2}{1+ (dy/dx)^{3/2}}  \tag{1}
$$
Apparently, $k$  is referred to as the geodesic curvature, which is defined by $k = T\cdot\nabla_TN$, where $T$ is the tangent vector and  $N$ is the normal vector of the curve.
I have never  encountered (1) before, and since it does not involve connection coefficients, I find it somewhat unusual. Therefore, I would like to know whether (1) is indeed the geodesic curvature ?
